# Java crear identificadores(nombres) de objetos automáticos

Tags: java, poo

Debo hacer una factura en java utilizando conceptos de POO.

Mediante un ciclo se debe ingresar los datos de cada producto(id, cantidad, precio, etc) y con esos datos creo el objeto producto el cual ya fue definido, en la clase Producto, esto dentro del mismo ciclo.

El ciclo se repite para pedir datos para un nuevo producto
El problema está en que cada vez que se repite el ciclo y debo ingresar datos para un nuevo producto por consecuencia debo crear un nuevo objeto producto el cual debe ser diferente a los objetos producto creados con los datos ingresados antes, lo que no sé es cómo poner identificadores diferentes para cada objeto producto de forma automática para así tener los objetos diferentes que necesito ya que no puedo solo hacer un objeto y cada vez que se ingrese los datos estos se sobrescriban.

Nota 1: no se pueden usar arrays

Nota 2: No pido que hagan mi problema, estoy pidiendo ayuda con los identificadores(del objeto es decir su nombre) y solo eso.

Agradezco sus comentarios

Esto es la estructura inicial que estaba haciendo y para probar solo inciuí el id del Producto

```
package proyectofactura;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean respuesta;
        //int i = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el id del producto");
            int idProducto = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(idProducto);
            Producto pro1 = new Producto(idProducto);
            System.out.println("¿Quiere ingresar otro producto?, si sí presione 1, sino cualquier letra ");
            int resp = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (resp == 1) {
                respuesta = true;
            } else {
                respuesta = false;
            }
            System.out.println(respuesta);

        }while(respuesta == true);
}
}
```

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema. Si no se puede usar arrays, que estructura podes utilizar para guardar multiples objetos del mismo tipo???

Comment: No dije que lo resuelvan por mí, específicamente solo pido ideas para crear los identificadores, por eso explico esa parte. Igual gracias por tu sugerencia

Comment: Cada que ingreses el id del producto verifica en otro método que ese id ya exista, si ya existe muestre un mensaje y vuelve a pedir que ingrese un nuevo id; otra solución es que ese id sea auto incremental en cada ciclo for

Comment: Sí bueno no eso en sí ya que me refiero al identificador del objeto es decir el nombre

Comment: que haras despues de crear esos objetos???? imprimir sus datos o alguna operacion?  de ser asi podes almacenar los datos del objeto en variables independientemente e ir operando hasta imprimirlos

Comment: La idea general cuando se trabaja con objetos, es ir almacenando cada objeto ya sea en un ``ArrayList`` o ``Arreglo`` de lo contrario solo tendrás el ultimo objeto (Producto) ingresado y no hay forma de poder saber si un producto ya ha sido ingresado si no existe un registro de los productos por ende no se puede realizar una búsqueda. El problema tmabién se resuelve con el uso de ``Map``

Comment: Después de crear los objetos usaré sus respectivos atributos para obtener los datos de la factura, por ejemplo imprimir todos los nombres de los productos ingresados con sus precioso @Dramaturgo

Comment: Pero si no usas un array, donde vas a guardar todos esos objetos?

Comment: Estaba pensando cuando ya tengo los valores en los objetos usar getters para obtenerlos y hacer los cálculos porque el problema mismo es que debo hacerlo sin arrays

Comment: @Karinarichavala entonces podrias hacer uso del mismo objeto pero obteniendo los valores diferente que pueda tener en cada iteracion y concatenarlos con una variable de tipo String [ejemplo](https://www.codiva.io/p/03f28360-596f-4b37-9852-6f6954b0659d)

Comment: Gracias algo así hice, ya mismo subo la solución que empleé